# Is there a backquote on the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Is there a backquote (backtick <kbd>`</kbd>) on the iPhone keyboard, and if so, where is it?

When I'm writing a post on a site in the SE family (especially SO), I want to use the backquote for inline code blocks. Under the single quote key, I've found two curly/angled quotes, but those (<kbd>’</kbd> and <kbd>‘</kbd>) don't seem to do the trick...

Comment: Another name for the character is [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

Answer (score 59):

The backtick/backquote was added to the iOS keyboard in 4.1. You need to switch to the numbers keypad and then press & hold apostrophe to access it. Once the variations show up - slide your finger without removing it from the screen. Remove your finger when it's over the correct <kbd>`</kbd> key.

Comment: iOS unnecessarily over complicate simple things.

Comment: Wow, having to do this 6 times when needing to put something in a markdown code block 

Answer (score 3):

It [seems like](http://stdout-dev-null.blogspot.com/2009/08/backtick-grave-accent-iphone.html) you have to resort to a hack to use the character:

1. Go to an email address field (e.g. open up Mail and compose a new message).
2. Go to the symbols keyboard (3rd one).
3. Type the <kbd>`</kbd> character located on the top left.
4. Copy and paste the character wherever you want.

Comment: Ouch. Especially in the iPhone world where opening up Mail means closing whatever app I'm in, which may or may not save its state... I'm pretty sure this answer is correct though.

Comment: This is far from the best solution - see the other answer that you simply hold the normal apostrophe until the menu of many variations of the character pops up and select the backtick by sliding your finger and releasing when it's over the ` character on iOS.

Comment: @bmike, I suppose this answer is the only one for iphones before 4?

Answer (score 0):

go into settings > general > keyboards > text replacement and add it with a phrase into your phone copying the backtick symbol to your clipboard and pasting in the shortcut.

ie: i put for phrase:  "' (quotation symbol apostrophe)
and shortcut: ```(3 backticks)

because in the english language thats not a thing that would really be typed in conjunction.

Comment: Does the answer from 2011 not work for you?